# How to prevent adding .editorconfig to one solution leading to StyleCop rules getting applied to every solution?

Tags: c#, stylecop, editorconfig

Say I have the following folder structure:

```
Root -> dir A -> dir B -> sln B
              -> dir C -> sln C
     -> sln A
```

There's stylecop.json present for all the solutions.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/master/StyleCop.Analyzers/StyleCop.Analyzers/Settings/stylecop.schema.json",
  "settings": {
    "documentationRules": {
      "companyName": "X",
      "copyrightText": "X"
    }
  }
}
```

But there's no .editorconfig file and the SA rules are not applied to the solutions (not sure if it's expected). Now, the moment I create a .editorconfig file for sln C, the SA rules start getting applied to A, B, C all solutions. How do we configure it to apply for a single solution only?

Comment: _"You can still set your own personal editor preferences in the Visual Studio Options dialog box. Those settings apply whenever you're working in a codebase **without an .editorconfig file, or when the .editorconfig file doesn't override a particular setting.** An example of such a preference is indent style—tabs or spaces."_ - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options?view=vs-2019

Comment: _"Now, the moment I create a .editorconfig file for sln C, the SA rules start getting applied to A, B, C all solutions"_ - sounds like you are saving the .editorconfig for sln C in root.  Save it in the same folder as the .sln file.

Comment: @Deleted No I don't want personal editor preference. I'm creating one for our dev team. Also, I'm creating the .editorconfig as a solution item for sln C only (i.e it is in same folder as sln C)

Comment: _"No I don't want personal editor preference"_ - **Read again** what I posted. _"Those settings apply whenever you're working in a codebase `without an .editorconfig file`"_ - either you saved the .editorconfig in the `wrong place` or you have defined equivalent settings in VS `itself`.

Comment: The above comment has not helped me. I have saved the config file in the correct place and I do not have "equivalent settings in VS itself" (if it were so, they'd be applied if I create a new solution but they don't). Any other help, anyone ?

Comment: Actually, why are you using **stylecop.json** anyway.  That's not the contemporary way to do it.  The rules should be in the actual **.editorconfig**.  You first add[`<EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>true</EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#enforcecodestyleinbuild) in your **.csproj** file _then_ add your [Code style analysis rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/overview#code-style-analysis) to the **.editorconfig** file.  Delete the **stylecop.json** files.

Comment: ...you might also want to look for any **Directory.Build.props** in the entire folder tree where your solutions are, all the way up to root as such a file adds global build directives to any project found in the same folder or child there-of.

Comment: @Deleted I was under the impression that .editorconfig file is required to enforce stylecop rules. I think editorconfig is used to configure all analyzer warnings... (but I can't say with 100% surety)

Comment: Originally when MS started to include the .editorconfig [spec](https://editorconfig.org/) it was just for _coding styling_, now code analysis rules can live in there too **but** you must add the above-mentioned `<EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>` element in your .csproj because analysis is disabled by default, even if you do have rules in your editorconfig.  **No plug-in required.**  VS2022 will then immediately analyse your code when you are viewing a file or making changes to it.  Pretty neat. :)

Answer (score 0):

[Update]: It's working.
There was a .editorconfig in root directory which probably messed it up. I am unable to think of any other reason.